# Как добавить в список текст без кавычек или апострофов?

Tags: python, python-3.x

При парсе создается массив переменных:
`[<b>uuee</b>, <b>uude</b>, <b>uses</b>, <b>ssde</b>]`
Как добавить в начало массива `<b>enrt</b>` ?
Через insert добавляет `'<b>enrt</b>'`
`['<b>enrt</b>', <b>uuee</b>, <b>uude</b>, <b>uses</b>, <b>ssde</b>]`

Comment: какой-то странный у вас "массив переменных". Если это строки, то они и должны быть в кавычках. Если нет, то там не должно быть тегов `bold`

Comment: bs4 так делает, а мне надо добавить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С bs4 не работал, но сейчас бегло полистал документацию, и, кажется, элементы вашего массива имеют тип Tag.

Чтобы проверить это, выведите для вашего исходного массива такое:

```
print(type(data[0]))
```

(где data - ваш массив)

Если выведется что-то такое `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>`, значит я угадал верно.

В этом случае вам нужно будет перед вставкой в массив руками создать из вашего значения объект класса Tag.

Насколько я могу судить по той же документации, это делается как-то так:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("<b></b>", 'html.parser')

new_tag = soup.b          # Создаём пустой тэг <b>
new_tag.append('enrt')    # Наполняем его вашим текстом

print(new_tag)

# Напечатает без кавычек: <b>enrt</b>
```

А дальше вы просто делаете insert элемента `new_tag` в ваш массив.

Comment: отработал на 100%, все как в аптеке))) респект. 2 дня бился.